# Permission denied when using FTP & filezilla

Tags: permissions, ftp

I'm using Ubuntu with [open game panel](http://www.opengamepanel.org/news.php)

When I use FTP in filezilla and try to upload a file I get:

```
553: Permission denied
```

In full:

```
Command:    CWD /
Response:   250 OK. Current directory is /
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (178,238,228,40,212,152)
Command:    STOR minecraft_server.jar
Response:   553 Can't open that file: Permission denied
Error:  Critical file transfer error
```

Comment: It may help to specify whether  you are connecting with ftp or sftp, whether you can see a directory listing once you are connected and whether you have been able to do this previously.  Error 553 is as you say permission denied, which would suggest you don't have write permissions to the filesystem.

Comment: here is logg errors log

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with open game panel, however the error (`553 Permission Denied`) is related to FTP.

It means that you don't have write permission on the directory/folder you are attempting to write to.

Make sure that the username you are logged in through in FTP has write/edit permissions on the directory/folder you are uploading to.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/h2kRYgtW

Answer (score 0):

Now you've expanded a little on the error, I think I see the issue.

At a glance it doesn't seem clear whether it's failing to read your local file (minecraft_server.jar) or failing to put it in the remote location, but I think it's the latter.

Note the message:

```
Current directory is /
```

You almost certainly do not want to put the file in the root of the filesystem.  Unless you are FTP'd in as root you probably can't write there anyway.

I suggest you change to your remote user's home directory:

```
cd /home/yourusername
```

Then try to put the file there.

If you're planning to do something else other than start Minecraft server from the command line once you've put the jar file there, you'll need to put it in the appropriate path instead, which will be in the documentation.

Comment: teach my i make first time this can you teach me how?